# How to access the data in the batch of a deep learning model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am training a Fully Connected deep learning model on the MNIST dataset, which has `3` layers `(512, 512, 10)`, and relu and softmax as activation functions. I am using Keras for the models. Is there any way to access the data in a batch of an epoch?

Suppose the batch size is 32, so I would like to see which data was used as input in that batch.

Comment: Yes. Please check, https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/ or https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/

Comment: @Innat these are ways of replacing the training function (model.fit), which I am aware of. However, I am looking for something that will allow me to pause the training and access the model to find the data in each batch.